# what does data[:,0] or data[:,1] mean in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I saw some pandas code which says

```
plt.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

I want to know what does data[:,0] and data[:,1] means?

Comment: A read of [any basic numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) would reveal this basic knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thas mean:

`data[:,0]` - > All the first column of the dataset

`data[:,1]` -> All the second colum of the dataset